# Angular EventEmitter & Output to open modal

Tags: angular

I know my life is going to be so much easier once parent/child child/parent communication clicks for me. In the mean time, here is what I have tried to accomplish.

In my module, I have a two subcomponents. The table which has a button that emits the event (in this case the userId) and the modal which should be listening for the event.

so starting at the table component I have a method that gets the userId that has been clicked:

```
editUser(id) {
    this.userId.emit(id);
}

<button class="btn btn-transparent py-0"
    tooltip="Edit User"
    container="body"
    (click)="editUser(row.userId)">
    <small><span class="fa fa-pencil text-secondary"></span></small>
</button>
```

then in my modal component I have another method that should have the userId passed into it.

```
openModal(id?) {
    console.log(id);
    this.modalService.open(this.content);
}
```

and then in my main component template i set to listen for the event

```
<header class="bg-white">
    <h4 class="text-primary my-0">{{ 'USERS.HEADING' | translate }}</h4>
    <div class="inner">
        <app-double-pitch-button></app-double-pitch-button>
    </div>
    <div class="utility">
        <div class="input-search">
            <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchText" type="text" placeholder="{{ 'COMMON.SEARCH' | translate }}">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded ml-5"
            (click)="firmModal.openModal()">
            {{ 'USERS.NEW_USER' | translate }}
        </button>
    </div>
</header>
<app-firm-table class="py-2 px-3" [searchText]="searchText"></app-firm-table>
<app-firm-modal #firmModal (openModal)="firmModal.openModal($event)"></app-firm-modal>
```

which should fire the `openModal()` method and also pass the id argument into it.

so obviously this isn't working or I wouldn't be posting here. What am I missing?

Comment: Assuming `userId` is an `@Output` in `this.userId.emit(id);`; where did you write it in your html? Again assuming the table component you have mentioned is `app-firm-table`, this component won't emit anything because it doesn't have the (userId) function in html.

Comment: in my table component I have userId as `@Output() userId = new EventEmitter<number>();`

Answer (score 2):

In the main component template set listen from the event (userId) from app-firm-table and set send event to app-firm-modal.

```
<app-firm-table class="py-2 px-3" (userId)="openModalInMainComponent($event)" [searchText]="searchText"></app-firm-table>
<app-firm-modal #firmModal [openModal]="openModalEvent"></app-firm-modal>
```

In main component ts file add:

```
public openModalEvent: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

openModalInMainComponent(id): void {
   this.openModalEvent.emit(id);
}
```

In modal component add:

```
@Input() openModal: EventEmitter<number>;
private openModalSubscribe: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
   ....
   this.openModalSubscribe = this.openModal.subscribe(event => {
       this.openModal(event);
   })
}
ngOnDestroy() {
   ...
   this.openModalSubscribe.unsubscribe();
}
```

In table component it should look like that:

```
@Output() userId: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

editUser(id) {
   this.userId.emit(id);
}
...
```